# Why does Bootstrap Autocomplete send vue.js router go to /#/exclamationmark?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Why does it happen that my Vue router navigates to `/#/!` without apparent reason?

This seems to happen when I fire an event from an autocomplete form built with [Bootstrap Autocomplete](https://bootstrap-autocomplete.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and trigger a function.

Calling the same function by clicking a button does not lead to the problem.

This is the parent component where the event is emitted to

```
 <style scoped>
 </style>
 <template>
   <div id="appspace">
     <div id="leftbar">
     </div>
     <div id="workarea">
       <div id="mapblock">
       </div>
       <div id="infoblock">
         <div class="form-group"><label for="gotoff">Go to</label>
           <autosuggest @locselect="locSelect($event)" id="gotoff"></autosuggest>
         </div>
         <button v-on:click="searchAround()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div id="rightbar">
     </div>
   </div>
 </template>
 <script>
 module.exports = {
     data: function () {
         return {
         };
     },
     components: {
         autosuggest: httpVueLoader('components/base/autosuggest.vue'),
     },
     mounted: function(){
     },
     destroyed: function(){
     },
     methods: {
         setMarkerInCenter: function(){
             this.locSelect({ value: { lng: 12, lat: 14 }})
         },
         locSelect: function(e) {
             console.log('locSelect');
             console.log(e);
         },
     },
 }
 </script>
```

and this is the component emitting the event:

```
 <style scoped>
   .autocomplete {
     position: relative;
     width: 130px;
   }
 
   .autocomplete-results {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
     height: 120px;
     overflow: auto;
   }
 
   .autocomplete-result {
     list-style: none;
     text-align: left;
     padding: 4px 2px;
     cursor: pointer;
   }
 
   .autocomplete-result:hover {
     background-color: #4AAE9B;
     color: white;
   }
 </style>
 <template>
   <div class="input-group">
     <input ref="ac" class="form-control">
     <div class="input-group-append">
       <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-compass" style="height:0.5em;padding:0;margin:0;margin-bottom:4px"></i></div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </template>
 <script>
 module.exports = {
     mounted: function(){
         var i = this.$refs.ac;
         var c = this
 
         $(i).autoComplete({ resolverSettings: { url: '/api/gc/autocomplete' } });
         $(i).on('autocomplete.select', function(e, sel) {
             e.preventDefault();
             c.$emit('locselect', sel);
             e.preventDefault();
         });
     },
 }
 </script>
```

Any leads as to how to debug this?

Comment: Add `event.preventDefault()` in the autocomplete function

Comment: @AlexHoffman - that does not seem to work either

Comment: Well, without seeing any code I cannot suggest anything else

Comment: @AlexHoffman - I know and thanks for trying. I'll strip things down and post code too. I was hoping more for directions in debugging than fixes

Comment: @AlexHoffman - added code, if you are inclined to check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the reason why this autocomplete changes the route, that behavoir
seems to be undocumented. But here's a method to temporarily prevent this behavior until you find the solution, add this global route guard to your router to prevent navigation to `'/#/!'` route:

### router.js

```js
const router = new VueRouter({ ... })

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  console.log(to)
  // TEMP PATCH: 
  // Autocomplete changes route to '/#/!'
  if (to.path !== '/#/!') { 
    next() 
  }
})
```

Just make sure that `console.log(to)` actually has a property `path === '/#/!'`

Comment: thanks! tried that, but evil autocomplete doesn't seem to go through there. My guess is things happen here https://github.com/xcash/bootstrap-autocomplete/blob/master/src/dropdown.ts#L199 - and that might be the start of a workaround. Any thoughts?

Comment: @simone that router rule prevents the route change no matter what triggers it. Just look at the result of the `console.log(to)` and make sure the `to.path` property equals `/#/!` when you trigger the route change from autocompleate. You might need to use `to.fullPath` instead of `to.path`, see what the console.log shows you

Comment: @simone other than that I cannot suggest anything else because I don't have enough information, I don't get how you're clicking that `<a>` tag by triggering autocomplete function, and since the question has 40+ views and no other responses, I guess no one else understand how exactly you're triggering that function either.

Comment: @simone perhaps you should open a new issue in the repo of this module on github and ask them why doesn't their documentation mention this behavior and how to make it work

Comment: I appreciate your help. Funnily enough beforeEach does not seem to capture the route change. I don't know what happens inside autusuggest, but patching it so that all instances of `#!` with `javascript:;`makes things work ok. Yes, I'll open an issue or get in touch some other way. Thanks again!

Comment: It looks like this has been patched but I haven’t tested the patched version yet